# How do I keep data live in Silverlight?

Tags: sql-server, silverlight, wcf

Say I have a GridView, the GridView will display the data from database through WCF.

The only way I can think of is using

1. A timer to keep on query from WCF (simplest).
2. The best way to do is get notification when data changes in
       database, so that would be using query notifications.  But now, the
       WCF is in the middle betweens the Silverlight Client and Database,
       so the query notification will only goes the WCF.  Then I will need
       to make make the WCF to use duplex communication.  (Sounds like overkill...)
3. Refresh...button.... (this is a joke)

Is there any better way doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to work for a company that makes medical software, and we had an application that had to monitor doctors and orders, and be constantly updated. We used a timer, just as you described above. There were some extra components to it - for example, we could change the sampling rate in software, so that during busy times, we could ping the DB more often, during slower times, less often. Caching was implemented as well. There was also a system in place to pull a smaller amount of data first, then pull more only if needed. For example, if a doctor hadn't made his rounds since the last update, then there was no need to check to see if patient data was updated. Stuff like that.

Comment: Yes, I seen such similar implementation.  We had a small table that will indicates if there is any changes on the datatable and versioning the database table.  So it pull the actual data only when there is data changes.  Timer with different sampling rate is nice idea, it saves a lots of bandwidth.  But I want to see if there is something similar to 2.  Really only pull the data when need to be pull, so we don't have to keep on ping the database (or WCF here).